# Android Permissions: Where are they described?

Tags: android, android-permissions

On the Google Play webpage for every application there is a permission section. Almost all of these applications uses some standard terminology to describe their permissions like "`READ PHONE STATUS AND IDENTITY`", "`SEND SMS`","`FULL INTERNET ACCESS`" etc. However on the [Android Developer's page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) the permissions are listed as constants and their descriptions but not the standard terminology found at the Google Play webpage of the application.

For eg.There is a `String Internet` with the description `Allows applications to open network sockets` but not the `FULL INTERNET ACCESS` permission which is generally used for this description.

Is there some link which provides a mapping of the permission constants to these standard permission notation?

Comment: Have a look at this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: I know this link. In fact, I linked it in my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"READ PHONE STATUS AND IDENTITY" this is nothing but **description about the permisson**.U can get the Description about all permission using **Packagemanger class** in android.**PermisionInfo** is the class which will give u the Description-

```
PermissionInfo pinfo = packageManager.getPermissionInfo("Specify permisson constant", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

pinfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for Manifest Permissions.
Which are defined in your project. Under `AndroidManifest.xml`

And a [list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) if you need

Eg. for some common permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```